# Can't correctly implement XNA interface IUpdateable in F# because of events

Tags: f#, event-handling, xna

I'm currently using F# and XNA for my new project, but got stuck when implementing XNA's IUpdateable interface. Specifically when I need to implement the event handlers.

This is what I have:

```
let enabledChanged = new DelegateEvent<System.EventHandler>()
```

and further down:

```
interface IUpdateable with
    ... // other stuff
    [<CLIEvent>]
    member self.EnabledChanged = enabledChanged.Publish
```

But i'm getting this error:

`Error  2   This expression was expected to have type     EventHandler     but here has type     EventHandler<EventArgs>`

I've tried several things but can't get this to work. What is expected to be there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried defining `enabledChanged` in the following way?

```
let enabledChanged = new Event<_>()
```

Answer (score 2):

as I see IUpdatable.EnabledChanged  has type System.EventHandler<System.EventArgs> but you are using System.EventHandler without type parameters.

```
type X() = 
    let enabledChanged = DelegateEvent<EventHandler<_>>()
    interface IUpdateable with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.EnabledChanged = enabledChanged.Publish
type Y() = 
    let enabledChanged = Event<EventHandler<_>, _>()
    interface IUpdateable with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.EnabledChanged = enabledChanged.Publish
```